# Custom options across sites

Tags: custom-options

We have an install of Magento running a number of sites for our travel company. The sites include a UK, US, European and South African store as well as a number of white label sites. The products within each store are the same with a number of them having a custom option for "Travel Date".

We've decided we'd like to make some dates unavailable from some sites whilst still being available for others. So for example the date '20th November 2014' would be available for users booking in the US or UK but not South Africa.

Selecting the correct 'Store View' from the top of the left hand column within a product, then selecting 'Custom Options' shows me the custom options for that product but removing one option removes it globally. Is there a way to remove a custom option for one store without removing it from the product completely?

Answer (score 1):

Custom options are global. You can only change the labels on a store view level.
So what you need is not really possible, not in a reasonable time frame